# Is there a way to have a calculated field in TypeORM returning a value of 'true' or 'false' having a condition joining a relation column?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to have a calculated field which will basically check if a related table contains a particular row. To be exact, I have a `Post` entity which has author as a relation (ManyToOne) to `User` entity; I have a query to get a single post by id, and I also want to add a field in the return `Post` object i.e. if the particular post is liked by me.

**Post Entity - Post.ts**

```js
@Entity()
export class Post extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.posts, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'author_id' })
    author: User

    @OneToMany(() => Like, (like) => like.post)
    likes: Like[]

    // ... other columns
}
```

**User Entity - User.ts**

```js
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string

    @OneToMany(() => Post, (post) => post.author)
    posts: Post[]

    @OneToMany(() => Like, (like) => like.author)
    likes: Like[]

    // ... other columns
}
```

**Like Entity - Like.ts**

```js
@Entity()
export class Like extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string

    @ManyToOne(() => Post, (post) => post.likes, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'post_id' })
    post: Post

    @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.likes, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'author_id' })
    author: User

    // ... other columns
}
```

**Get Post Controller - /post/[id].ts**

```js
export const get = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { id } = req.params
    const { user_id } = req // simplified version of JWT token

    const postRepository = db.getRepository(Post)

    const post = await postRepository
        .createQueryBuilder('post')
        .where('post.id = :id', { id })
        .leftJoinAndSelect('post.author', 'author')
        .getOne()
    // here I want a field called 'likedByMe'

    // ... other logic
}
```

The above end point return this (simplified):

```json
{
  "id": "...",
  "created_at": "2022-05-28T20:05:54.060Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-05-29T15:18:17.525Z",
  "content": "<p>...</p>\n",
  "author": {
    "id": "...",
    "username": "john",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "avatar": "https://....cloudfront.net"
  },
```

I need to add a field called `isLikedByMe` in the response which will return a boolean value.

Any help is really appreciated! I am sorry if I have used any wrong terminology, I am pretty new to TypeORM or any complicated queries. Thank you